Verifying the integrability condition of a deterministic volatility function
Suppose there is integrability condition:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^T\frac{\sigma^2(t)}{T-t}dt\right]<\infty
\end{equation}
for an arbitrary volatility function. Suppose I nominate the deterministic function:
\begin{equation}
\sigma(t)=\sigma \sqrt{T-t}
\end{equation}
where $\sigma$ is a constant. My intuition is the following (please correct me if wrong):
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^T\frac{\sigma^2(t)}{T-t}dt\right]&=\int_0^T\frac{\sigma^2(T-t)}{T-t}dt\\
&=\sigma^2T.
\end{align}
and then the condition holds for some finite $T$. Is this correct? My concern is that the definition may imply as $T\to \infty$, in which case my justification would not hold!

Well the expectation is finite for every fixed $T$, but not as $T \to \infty$, as you state. Now it depends on what 'the definition' requires. When you state the condition at the beginning of the question, you don't say anything about $T$, so we don't know what is required.
